# Where to install mariadb-devel and python34-mysql-debug packages for python in a split app server / db server environment

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

In order for **Python** to talk to **MariaDB** I need to install mariadb-devel and python34-mysql-debug packages before using pip to install mysqlclient. I have done this with Python and MariaDB on a single server.  Now, I'm installing this in an environment with two servers: AppServer which runs Python code and DBServer which is running MariaDB.    So, do maradb-devel and python34-mysql-debug need to be installed on AppServer or on DBServer?

> Both servers are running RHEL 7.4.
>
> MariaDB is version 10.1
>
> Python is version 3.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mariadb-devel and python34-mysql-debug packages need to be installed on the application server where Python is running.  I tested this and it is working - I was able to run a simple Python script and connect to the database on the other server.